# Substringing a QR code and enter automatically in a form field in Zoho

Tags: javascript, arrays, zoho

I'm using the form field in Zoho and I want to scan a license disk.

This is the license disk code I get from the QR reader

```
 %MVL1CC17%0139%4024B00K%1%4024047DWMR8%12343GP%WMS659W%Pick-up/Bakkie%FORD%RANGER%White/White%abcdefghijklmnop%2018-06-30%
```

Now I want it to scan and substring each individual item for example:

```
License plate number = 12343GP
vin number = abcdefghijklmnop
color = white
model = ranger
make = ford
type= bakkie
?? =??
```

I want to scan one time and it should automatically put it in the desired fields color make type etc..

I have tried putting the fields together but then I have to scan the same disk 5 times should I make a formula field then put in a script?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using % as a delimiter, then use pop and shift to remove the first and last blank elements:

```
var str = "%MVL1CC17%0139%4024B00K%1%4024047DWMR8%12343GP%WMS659W%Pick-up/Bakkie%FORD%RANGER%White/White%abcdefghijklmnop%2018-06-30%";

strArray = str.split('%');
strArray.shift();
strArray.pop();
```

Then, if you like, you can access them like this:

```
var obj = {
  plateNumber: strArray[5],
  vinNumber: strArray[11],
  color: strArray[10],
  model: strArray[9],
  make: strArray[8],
  type: strArray[7]
};

console.log(obj.plateNumber); // returns '12343GP'
```